# ERROR: whose view is not in the window hierarchy. Spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I will try to explain this best i can. Okay i am using SpriteKit in xcode5. Inside Myscene.m i have a method called:

```
-(void)presentViewController
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyView"];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in my NSTimeintervalUpdate method i have a code that says

```
if(score >= 3)
{
    [self presentViewController]
}
```

All this code brings up the view controller i want from the storyboard like it should with no problems but in this view controller it has a button that links up back to the game. When you click the button it goes right back to the game like it should. Well during the game instead of going back to my ViewController at a score of "3" like it did the first time, it just continues to count up and provides the following error message in the log:

```
2014-07-12 22:40:27.710 tests[337:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController2: 0xc354e40> on <ViewController: 0x9960b80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My intention is to have my game (Myscene.m) and when the game is over is to have a game over screen (ViewController). And then from this view controller i want it to have a play again button that is linked back to Myscene.m(which i simply did by making button and control and drag to the view controller that handles my SKScene) and continues to repeat process but it will only do this process once and then it fails to loop back around and instead presents the above error.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't present View Controller from `SKScene` directly. Use `NSNotificationCenter` to tell parent View Controller to present another View Controller:

In `GameSceneViewController.m`:

```
@interface GameSceneViewController

@property (nonatomic) int score;

@end

@implementation GameSceneViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(presentMyViewController:) name:@"presentMyViewController" object:nil];
}
- (void)presentMyViewController:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.score = notification.userInfo[@"score"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:(segue identifier) sender:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:(segue identifier])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        MyViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        vc.score = self.score;
    }
}


@end
```

Then in `GameScene.m` call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"presentMyViewController" object:nil userInfo:@{"score" : self.score}];
```

Comment: Also what specifically goes inside selector:@selector() and what goes in "seque identifier"?  Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Okay i have figured out what you have answered and it worked great but now theres a new problem..... after it pulls up the ViewController using your code. Whenever i press the UIButton to go back to the game, it automatically pulls up the ViewController again right away instead of waiting for the score to go up to "3".

Comment: Check your `postNotificationName:object:` call. Call it only when game is over. Try to debug it. I don't know anything about your game scene as you didn't provide a code for that, so this is something you should figure out by yourself.

Comment: I figured it out thank you very much! and one last question. During my game i have a int score in my MyScene.m that keeps track of the players time which is the players score, when the game is over how do i take that int score and display it on my view controller?

Comment: Will both Segue identifiers read the same exact thing? I understand what i should put after isEqualToString: @"Name of segue" but what goes in the beginning segue identifier right after "if"

Comment: Yes, that should be the same segue identifier you used before

Comment: I am having a problem with this method recognizing my "score". It says property of score not found on object on type of view controller. my GameSceneViewController is connect to Myscene.h/m. In Myscene.m is where i have defined my score after @implementation as { int score; }. i imported Myscene into GameSceneViewController but it still won't recognize my int score. just added info: GameSceneViewController is where my skscene is presented but in MyScene.m is where all my game code is entered.

Comment: Declare `score` property in `MyViewController` (game over view controller)